# Why is this vb code giving an implicit conversion warning?

Tags: vb.net, random, mersenne-twister

This vb [Mersenne Twister](https://www.programmingalgorithms.com/algorithm/mersenne-twister?lang=VB.Net) code from ProgrammingAlgorithms.com seems to work, but gives a baffling "implicit conversion" warning in VS 2015. The exact message is: "warning BC42016: Implicit conversion from 'UInteger' to 'Integer'." This occurs eight times in only the `Reload()` function, everywhere `p0`, `P2`, `pM`, and `Increment` are used. From what I can tell, these and `state` are all clearly defined as `UInteger`, and adding any `CUInt()` to specifically cast them has no effect. Where is this implicit conversion coming from and what is the correct remedy?

Comment: I'd post their code, but their copyright says it forbids reproduction and republishing.

Comment: `Increment` and `Decrement` both take an int32 as the param, but those are all UInt vars, thus a conversion is required, since you (they) didnt do so, you get the warning

Comment: @rdtsc their copyright says you can distribute and use the code for personal, commercial and noncommercial use, just not the rest of their content.

Comment: But `Increment` is overloaded - one version takes Int32's, the other takes UIntegers. If I comment out the Int32 version, nothing changes - so it is using the UInteger version.  My guess it has something to do with `state`.

Comment: Its a bad implementation.  A RNG should inherit from Random so it can be used as a random object with standard methods like `Next()`.  Comparing the output with 2 other implementations all three using the same seed, it generates the wrong values.

Comment: BTW, its actually complaining about the return - the state array is defined to hold UIntegers but for indexing you'd still use an Int32

Comment: Not for nothing, but I'd be very careful of the code from that site.  The code for shuffling is a model of inefficiency: it takes 3 to 12 times longer on 10k elements.

Comment: Agreed, I thought this would be very slow. Threw this `Random()` into a 1M loop; it took 247mS to execute. Better than I'd expected! So is the "warning" just that indexes to all arrays in VB are Integer? I'm able to remedy the warning by typing the index: `state(CInt(Increment(p0)))` but am unsure about possible loss of data. Everything remains in-bounds though, for billions of iterations anyways.

Comment: When more than one person comments and you want one of them to see a comment use @ + username as in @rdtsc to ping them - you get pinged for everything because it is your question.  The main problem with that MT is that it generates the wrong numbers (and only UInts).  Part of the point of the MT is that you can have 2 separate instances and they will generate the same sequence of values given the same seed.  247ms is pretty fast, mine will do 1M individually in ~550ms, but will create a 1M *series* (another missing feature in that MT) in 93ms

Answer (score 2):

Go to project properties.
A new tab will open with side menu. Select Compile from this side menu.
Now there will be a table on the right hand side. 
Under this table there will be a column named "Condition" and another column "Notification"

Select the implicit conversion and set its notification to None by clicking on the dropdown under the column heading "Notification"
Similarly Set value None for the Late binding, call could fail at runtime, and implicit type, object assumed conditions to None.

Rebuild the solution and viola!!!

@rdtsc